# laravel maatwebsite excel export currency row

Tags: php, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Im using the [laravel maatwebsite packag](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export#format)e to export an excel sheet.
One column contains euro currency, so im trying to make a currency column for the data.

my code for the columns:

```
    $sheet->setColumnFormat(array(
        'G' =>  \PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER_00,
        'H' =>  "[$EUR ]#,##0.00_-",
        'I' =>  \PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_CURRENCY_EUR_SIMPLE,
    ));
```

with no luck, when for example 5 (without any decimals) is inserted in one of these columns the data looks like 5 instead of € 5.00

How is the formating set in the correct way?

Answer (score 4):

You can add `data-format` attribute to`<td>`

Example:

```
<td data-format="$#,##0_-">Price</td>
<td data-format="0.00">Price</td>
<td data-format="0%">Percentage</td>
<td data-format="dd/mm/yy">Date</td>
<td data-format="h:mm:ss AM/PM">Date/Time</td>
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  Where did you find this in documentation?

Comment: @Davron Achilov, is this working on laravel export to excel?

Comment: @RosidinBima, yes, it's working for export

Answer (score 0):

Hey im not sure about proper method but this is simple trick :P

```
foreach($jobs  as $index =>$row){
$data=array($index+1,$row->invoice_no,$row->customer_name,'€'.$row->amount);
$sheet->fromArray(array($data),null,'A6',false,false);
  }

$sheet->appendRow(8, array(
           'TOTAL','€'.$sum 
));
```

Comment: If you use this trick, the value will be converted to a string. You can't make calculations in excel with strings.

Comment: Yes you can't but you can do calculation in the function level not in a sheet .

Comment: I've added an answer where the value will be formatted to a accounting value.

Answer (score 0):

With the above answer your value will be converted to a string value in Excel. I've used the code snipped below to set the format on a accounting value.

```
$sheet->setColumnFormat(array(
    'C2' => '[$€-2] * #,##0.00;-[$€-2] * #,##0.00_-;_-[$€-2] * "-"??_-;_-@_-',
));
```

Answer (score 0):

First user interface like:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnFormatting
and implement with class (WithColumnFormatting)

 public function columnFormats(): array
    {
        return [
            'I' => '₹#,##0.00'
           ];
    }
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.