# How can I custom number format in laravel excel maatwebsite?

Tags: excel, laravel, number-formatting, laravel-5.6, laravel-excel

I read in this tutorial : https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.0/exports/column-formatting.html

My script export like this :

```
namespace App\Exports;
...
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnFormatting;
class SummaryExport implements WithColumnFormatting
{
    ...
    public function columnFormats(): array
    {
        return [
            'H' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER_COMMA_SEPARATED2
    }
}
```

For example the real value = 30132,7531

If I use the format in my script above, it will to be : 30.132,75

It doesn't match the format I want

I want the format like this : 30.133

I try custom the format in the `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat;`

I add this :

```
const FORMAT_NUMBER_CUSTOM = '#,##0';
```

And I add the const to my script above, it works, the result 30.133

I want to ask whether this is the right way? And can I edit the number format inside the vendor folder?

This `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat;` located in vendor folder

Comment: Don’t overwrite the vendor file. create a class and then extend this class and then overwrite property and method in your class

Comment: @rkj I had do it and it works. Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you should define `FORMAT_NUMBER_COMMA_SEPARATED2` constant within your `SummaryExport` export class.

Answer (score 0):

refer to: [laravel maatwebsite excel export currency row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38469927/laravel-maatwebsite-excel-export-currency-row/57311723#57311723)

you can also use data format in your table:

```
<td data-format="0.00">Price</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnFormatting;
    
class SensusIndividuExport implements WithColumnFormatting {
  public function columnFormats(): array
            {
                return [
                    'A' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER,
                    'B' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER,
                    'C' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT,
                ];
            }
        }
```

I hope it can help you...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).